# Failed to decode json error when sending data to API using Guzzle

Tags: php, api, request, guzzle

I am trying to update data in API using Guzzle. And during running I meet this `Failed to decode json` error. Below is what I've done:

```
$client = new Client([
        'headers' => [
            'Authorization' => 'Bearer ' . env('API_TOKEN'),
            'Content-Type' => 'application/json',
            'Accept' => 'application/json',
        ]
    ]);

    $api_link = env('KINGTIME_API');
    $updateAPIlink = $api_link . 'daily-schedules/' . $emp_key . '/' . $date;
    $response = $client->put(
        $updateAPIlink,
        json_decode(json_encode(['form_data' => $tobeUpdated])
    ), true);
```

The above code returns the `Failed to decode JSON` error and data inside my `$tobeUpdated` variable is like this:

```
array(8) {
        ["workPlaceDivisionCode"]=>
        string(7) "testeam"
        ["clockInSchedule"]=>
        string(0) "2019-01-01T19:00+09:00"
        ["clockOutSchedule"]=>
        string(0) "2019-01-01T19:00+09:00"
        ["workFixedStart"]=>
        string(22) "2019-01-01T08:00+09:00"
        ["workFixedEnd"]=>
        string(22) "2019-01-01T19:00+09:00"
    }
```

When I try to test in Postman, it receives data in like this formnat:

```
   {
        "workPlaceDivisionCode": "testeam",
        "clockInSchedule": "2019-01-01T09:00+09:00",
        "clockOutSchedule": "2019-01-01T18:00+09:00",
        "workFixedStart": "2019-01-01T08:00+09:00",
        "workFixedEnd": "2019-01-01T19:00+09:00"
    }
```

Is the error from the API itself or from my data feed? If on my data feed, how can I make a date like the format to feed using Postman? This is my first time to work on API.

Comment: What date format does the Postman API require?

Comment: @Joseph_J In this format `2019-01-01T08:00+09:00`.

Comment: I don't know why you even encode/decode, however, try to isolate this steps and use [json_last_error](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-last-error.php)

Comment: What version of PHP are you using?

Comment: @Quasimodo'sclone I'm using encode/decode to solve the error.

Comment: @Joseph_J I'm using PHP 5.6.38

Comment: The `put` method seems to expect an associative array, not an object as returned by `json_encode`

Comment: @Quasimodo'sclone How to do it though?

Comment: https://web.archive.org/web/20150116073119/http://guzzle.readthedocs.org/en/latest/clients.html

Answer (score 0):

I think your going about this the wrong way:

Try simplifying this section of your code:

```
$response = $client->put(
        $updateAPIlink,
        json_decode(json_encode(['form_data' => $tobeUpdated])
    ), true); //<--Was this "true" suppose to be part of your json_decode or a value to be added to the client?
```

To this:

```
$response = $client->put(
  $updateAPIlink,
  array(
    'form_data' => $tobeUpdated
  )
);
```

The data that you are getting from Postman is in the JSON format.  You need to convert the JSON string to an object or array and then you will be able to access your values.

Like so:

```
echo '<pre>';

$json = ' {

  "workPlaceDivisionCode": "testeam",
  "clockInSchedule": "2019-01-01T09:00+09:00",
  "clockOutSchedule": "2019-01-01T18:00+09:00",
  "workFixedStart": "2019-01-01T08:00+09:00",
  "workFixedEnd": "2019-01-01T19:00+09:00"

}';

//To get the data as an object:
$object = json_decode($json);

var_dump($object);
echo '<br>';

echo $object->clockInSchedule . '<br><br>';

//To get the data as an array us the "TRUE" flag:
$array = json_decode($json, true);

var_dump($array);
echo '<br>';

echo $array['clockInSchedule'] .'<br><br>';

echo '</pre>';
```

Let me know if it helps.

Comment: Thanks for this but it has the same error. And with your clarification on the `true`, it is part of json decode. thanks,

Comment: What was the error as printed on your screen?  The reason I ask is that your previous error was a json related error and I removed all the json from your code.  So it should not be the same error.  Unless it is a json error on a different page.